# SQL Server comma delimiter for money datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, delimiter

I import Excel files via SSIS to SQL-Server. I have a temp table to get everything in nvarchar. For four columns I then cast the string to money type and put in my target table.

In my temp table one of those four columns let me call it X has a comma as the delimiter the rest has a dot. Don't ask me why, I have everything in my SSIS set the same.
In my Excel the delimiter is a comma as well.

So now in my target table I have everything in comma values but the X column now moves the comma two places to the right and looks like this:

**537013,00** instead of **5370,13** which was the original cell value in the temp and excel column.

I was thinking this is a culture setup problem but then again it should or shouldn't work on all of these columns.

a) Why do I receive dot values in my temp table when my Excel displays comma?

b) how can I fix this? Can I replace the "," in the temp table with a dot?

**UPDATE**

I think I found the reason but not the solution:

In this X column in excel the first three cells are empty - the other three columns all start with 0. If I fill these three cells of X with 0s then I also get the dot in my temp table and the right value in my target table. But of course I have to use the Excel file as is.
 Any ideas on that?

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below. It checks whether the string value being converted to money is of numeric data type.  If the string value is of numeric data type, then convert it to money data type, otherwise, return a NULL value. And it also replaces the decimal symbol and the digit grouping symbol of the string value to match the expected decimal symbol and digit grouping symbol of SQL Server.

```
DECLARE @MoneyString VARCHAR(20)
SET @MoneyString = '$ 1.000,00'
SET @MoneyString = REPLACE(REPLACE(@MoneyString, '.', ''), ',', '.')
SELECT CAST(CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(@MoneyString) = 1
                 THEN @MoneyString
                 ELSE NULL END AS MONEY)
```

As for the reason why you get comma instead dot I have no clue. My first guess would be cultural settings but you already checked that. What about googling, did you get some results?

Answer (score 0):

First the "separator" in SQL is the decimal point: its only excel that is using the comma. You can change the formatting in excel: you should format the excel column as money and specify a decimal point as the separator. Then in the SSIS import wizard split out the transformation of the column so it imports to a money data type. Its a culture thing, but delimiter tends to be used in the context of signifying the end of one column and the start of the next (as in csv)

HTH

Comment: there's a reason I can't use anything but nvarchar since these numeric columns could all be empty in Excel or could even contain text (misplaced by the user)

Answer (score 0):

Well thats a longstanding problem with excel. It uses the first 30 or so rows to infer data type. It can lead to endless issues. I think your solution has to be to process everything as a string in the way Yaroslav suggested, or supply an excel template to have data predefined and formatted data type columns, which then have the values inserted. Its a pita.